# Вывод разного значения элементам с одним классом

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно чтобы каждый прогресс бар мог показывать разное значение, которое я задаю в id.
Пробовал через массив айдишников, но двойная итерация все ломает. Скорее всего надо через `this` , но не пойму как

```js
$('body').click(function() {
  var IDArray = [];
  $(".progress").each(function(){IDArray.push($(this).attr("id"))}); // Беру массив айди
      var i = 0;
      var a = 0;
      var c = "d00"; //Цвет
      var test = setInterval(function(){
        if(i == $(".progress").attr("id")) { // Останавливаю
          return;
        }else{
          i = i + 1;
          a = i/100;
          var rd = document.getElementsByClassName("progress")[0].getAttribute("r"); // Радиус прогресса
          var x = rd*2*Math.PI;
          var p = x * a;

          $(".progress").attr("stroke-dasharray", p + ", " + x);
          $(".progress").attr("stroke", "#"+ c); // Задаю цвет
          $("text").text(i + "%");
        }
      },15);
});
```

```css
.progress{
  fill: #f2f2f2;
  stroke-width: 10;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  cx: 75;
  cy: 75;
  }
.center{
  fill: #f2f2f2;
  }
text{
  fill: #000;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
 }
svg{
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <circle id="70" class="progress" r="70" />
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75" y="90" />
</svg>
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <circle id="90" class="progress" r="70" />
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75" y="90" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не остановили таймаут, у вас бесконечно высчитывается `i`, для этого есть метод `clearInterval()`. Нужно обращаться к текущему элементу, вы обращаетесь ко всем с классом `.progress`. Зачем вы создаете массив, если потом к нему не обращаетесь, он бесполезен в вашем коде. Не обязательно тянуть целую библиотеку ради нескольких строк кода.

```js
function init() {
  var diagram = document.getElementsByClassName('progress');
  for (var i = 0; i < diagram.length; i++) {
    diagram[i].onclick = handleClick;
  }
}
window.onload = init;

function handleClick(e) {
  var rad = e.target.id;
  processRad(rad);
}

function processRad(rad) {
  var a = 0;
  var c = "d00"; //Цвет
  var i = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (++i <= rad) {
      a = i / 100;
      var rd = document.getElementById(rad).getAttribute("r"); // Радиус прогресса
      var x = rd * 2 * Math.PI;
      var p = x * a;

      document.getElementById(rad).setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", p + ", " + x);
      document.getElementById(rad).setAttribute("stroke", "#" + c); // Задаю цвет
      document.getElementById(rad).nextElementSibling.innerHTML = (i + "%");
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 15);
}
```

```css
.progress {
  fill: #f2f2f2;
  stroke-width: 10;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  cx: 75;
  cy: 75;
}

.center {
  fill: #f2f2f2;
}

text {
  fill: #000;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
}

svg {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <circle id="70" class="progress" r="70" />
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75" y="90" />
</svg>
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <circle id="90" class="progress" r="70" />
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75" y="90" />
</svg>
```

P.s. Не лучшая практика задавать процент через ид, а если у вас будет более одного элемента с одинаковым процентом, а следовательно ид. Корректной работы не будет.

Comment: Через что лучше задавать процент? Атрибута value у этого тега нет. Можно ли сделать обработчик события не на клик, а на скролл?

Comment: Например через атрибут `data-*`. Можно.